# Dynamic options on whiptail got not printed

Tags: shell, jq, whiptail

I have a json file which provides options for a 'whiptail' checkbox or radiolist. I grab them, make some redactions and wanna use them to show as options:

`defaults.json` file:

```
{"displays":
  [
    {"id": "320x240", "default":"on", "description":"320x240 (native resolution of 3.2 TFT-Display)", "hdmi_group":"2", "hdmi_mode":"87","hdmi_cvt":"320 240 60 1 0 0 0"},
    {"id": "640x480", "default":"off", "description":"640x480", "hdmi_group":"2","hdmi_mode":"87", "hdmi_cvt":"3240 240 60 1 0 0 0"},
    {"id": "720x540", "default":"off", "description":"720x540", "hdmi_group":"2","hdmi_mode":"87", "hdmi_cvt":"3240 240 60 1 0 0 0"},
    {"id": "800x600", "default":"off", "description":"800x600", "hdmi_group":"2","hdmi_mode":"87", "hdmi_cvt":"3240 240 60 1 0 0 0"},
    {"id": "1024x768", "default":"off", "description":"1024x768", "hdmi_group":"2","hdmi_mode":"87", "hdmi_cvt":"3240 240 60 1 0 0 0"},
    {"id": "1280x720", "default":"off", "description":"1280x720 (16:9)", "hdmi_group":"2","hdmi_mode":"87", "hdmi_cvt":"3240 240 60 1 0 0 0"},
    {"id": "1600x900", "default":"off", "description":"1600x900 (16:9)", "hdmi_group":"2","hdmi_mode":"87", "hdmi_cvt":"3240 240 60 1 0 0 0"},
    {"id": "1920x1080", "default":"off", "description":"1920x1080 (16:9)", "hdmi_group":"2","hdmi_mode":"87", "hdmi_cvt":"3240 240 60 1 0 0 0"}
  ]
}
```

The `jq` script

```
displays=$(cat defaults.json | jq -r -j '.displays[] | "\(.id) \"\(.description)\" \(.default) "')
```

which gives me the following output (which works when I paste it directly into the `[tag item status]` position:

```
320x240 "320x240 (native resolution of 3.2 TFT-Display)" on 640x480 "640x480" off 720x540 "720x540" off 800x600 "800x600" off 1024x768 "1024x768" off 1280x720 "1280x720 (16:9)" off 1600x900 "1600x900 (16:9)" off 1920x1080 "1920x1080 (16:9)" off
```

This one works perfectly:

```
whiptail --title "Display setup" --radiolist  "Choose your display" 20 78 8 320x240 "320x240 (native resolution of 3.2 TFT-Display)" on 640x480 "640x480" off 720x540 "720x540" off 800x600 "800x600" off 1024x768 "1024x768" off 1280x720 "1280x720 (16:9)" off 1600x900 "1600x900 (16:9)" off 1920x1080 "1920x1080 (16:9)" off 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
```

**BUT** when I try to add them through the variable `$displays`, `whiptail` only spits out the "help" file.

**This is not working**

```
whiptail --title "Display setup" --radiolist  "Choose your display" 20 78 8 $displays 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
```

**What I am doing wrong, why is this not working?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `$displays` variable will simply be split on whitespace (with the default value of the `IFS` variable), without caring about the quotes and such (`"1920x1080 (16:9)"` will be passed to `whiptail` as two arguments, `"1920x1080` and `(16:9)"`, not as a single argument containing `1920x1080 (16:9)`. In cases like this, I warmly recommend using `set -x` to figure out what arguments are really passed to commands.

Try this instead:

```
jq -r '.displays[]|.id,.description,.default|@sh' defaults.json |
   xargs whiptail --title "Display setup" --radiolist  "Choose your display" 20 78 8
```

`whiptail` seems to always use stdout as the handle to the terminal, so if used in a command substitution, something a bit more complex is needed:

```
res=$(jq -r '.displays[]|.id,.description,.default|@sh' defaults.json |
   xargs whiptail --output-fd 3 --title "Display setup" --radiolist  "Choose your display" 20 78 8 3>&1 >/dev/tty)
echo "$res"
```

Comment: spits out: `xargs: illegal option -- d`

Comment: ok, I've modified it. The `-d` option to `xargs` is GNU-only.

Comment: Cool, it seems to be working: Can you disclose me why capturing the selected result `choosenvalue=$(THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE)` in a variable keeps my shell in a stucking status? 
Full example:
`choosenvalue$(jq -r '.displays[]|.id,.description,.default|@sh' defaults.json |
   xargs whiptail --title "Display setup" --radiolist  "Choose your display" 20 78 8)`

Comment: When I do the exact same example with `dialog` instead of `whiptail` everything works fine: `selected_display=$(echo $displays|xargs dialog --separate-output --checklist "Select Tags To Change" 0 0 0 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)`

Comment: `dialog` is probably smarter and is directly opening `/dev/tty` or is using stderr as a handle as the controlling terminal; anyways, I've updated the answer with a `a=$(... whiptail)` example.

Comment: Creating an array worked great for me, followed this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64614446/1382345